# Delphi XE - read style property of HTML objects

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer, delphi-xe, tembeddedwb

I am using the class `TEmbeddedWB` to Access HTML elements in an embedded Web Browser in a Delphi program.

After much googling I can't come up with a solution for the following issue: How to directly read style properties of objects?

I tried:

```
Event.srcElement.getAttribute('style', 0)
```

and it returns (in CodeSite Live Viewer) `[object MSStyleCSSProperties]`

```
 Event.srcElement.getAttribute('style.display', 0)
```

returns an empty string (but in the code it is defined as `block`). I guess, this ominous object can be accessed some way to read the declared (or computed?) CSS properties; but I can't figure out how it can be achieved. To what type of variable should I assign the return value of `getAttribute('style', 0)`? Will the result be as declared or as computed?

There is no type `MSStyleCSSProperties` declared.

Any help would be appreciated.

I am a Delphi beginner. Sorry if this question is nooby.

Comment: If you downvote be so kind to describe the reason; the question is in my opinion well-written and clear.

Comment: It would make it easier for people to help you if you could show a simple example of the HTML you are working on, and the code you have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IHTMLElement` has a property named `style` which is a `IHTMLStyle` object, and that object has some useful methods and properties that can help you.

Check this out:

```
Tag:IHTMLElement; // <div style="display: none;">

Memo1.Lines.Add(Tag.style.cssText); //Outputs "display: none;"
Memo1.Lines.Add(Tag.style.display); //Outputs "none"
```

Answer (score -1):

You should assign the return value of getAttribute function to a string:

```
var
StyleProperty     : string;

StyleProperty := Event.srcElement.getAttribute('style', 0);
```

Comment: No, it's wrong. As I already have written, the return value after such an assignment is `[object MSStyleCSSProperties]`.